# "Your app is sending events via server to server and does not send SKAdNetwork events automatically." - Facebook Ads error

Tags: ios, facebook

I am getting the following error when creating an iOS 14 Facebook Ad Campaign:

> Confirm SKAdNetwork API Setup: Your app is sending events via server
> to server and does not send SKAdNetwork events automatically. Go to
> Events Manager to confirm you have the SKAdNetwork API set up for your
> app. (#2446695)

[image]

I messaged Facebook support and they told me:

> Can you please implement either of the standard events supported for
> AEO: Complete Registration, Initiated Checkout, Purchase, Add To Cart,
> Content View, Level Achieved and once you start seeing requests for
> these standard events in Events Manager you should edit the events you
> have currently setup for SKAdNetwork ... and after adding the event to
> your config you should be able to create your campaigns.

So I did that and implemented the following event code on my iOS app to log a Registration Event:

```
let registrationEvent: AppEvents.Name = AppEvents.Name(rawValue: "FBSDKAppEventNameCompletedRegistration")
AppEvents.logEvent(registrationEvent, parameters: ["RegistrationMethod": "email"])
```

I don't know if this is the correct event to log but I just got it from this [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKAppEvents/).

I then added it to my event config:

[image]

And have successfully received an event:

[image]

however I'm still getting the `Confirm SKAdNetwork API Setup: Your app is sending events via server to server and does not send SKAdNetwork events automatically` error. And that event also doesn't appear under "Standard Events" - I had to filter to "All Events" for it to show up which means it may be seen as a standard event (did I input the wrong parameters for the event logging?).

Any help would be appreciated - all I want to do is create a Facebook Ad for my iOS 14 app.

Answer (score 4):

I think that this is a temporary problem caused by Facebook interruption, if you check it now you should start seeing events.

> From October 6 - October 11, Facebook Audience Network monetization data reporting was interrupted. The technical issue that prevented reporting has been resolved.

Comment: Error is still showing up unfortunately